# How can I test Stripe.js using poltergeist and Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara, stripe-payments, poltergeist

I've been going nuts trying to write an automated test for my user sign up page. Users will be charged a recurring subscription via Stripe. They input their basic details (email, password, etc) and their credit card details on the same form, then the following flow happens:

1. (On the client-side) stripe.js makes an AJAX request to Stripe's servers, which (assuming everything is valid) returns a credit card token.
2. My javascript fills in a hidden input in the HTML form with the credit card token, and submits the form to my Rails server.
3. (Now on the server-side): I validate the user's basic details. If they're invalid, return (because there's no point charging them via Stripe if e.g. their email address is invalid so they can't create an account anyway.)
4. If they're valid, attempt to create a `Stripe::Customer` object, add the right subscription and charge them using Stripe's ruby gem etc.

All of this works perfectly fine... except I can't figure out how to test it. Testing step #4 is easy enough as it takes place on the server-side so I can mock out the Stripe calls with a gem like VCR.

Step #1 is what's giving me trouble. I've tried to test this using both `puffing-billy` and the `stripe-ruby-mock` gem, but nothing works. Here's my own javascript (simplified):

```
    var stripeResponseHandler = function (status, response) {
      console.log("response handler called");
      if (response.error) {
        // show the errors on the form
      } else {
        // insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        $("#credit_card_token").val(response.id);

        // Now submit the form.
        $form.get(0).submit();
      }
    }


    $form.submit(function (event) {
      // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
      $submitBtn.prop("disabled", true);
      event.preventDefault();

      console.log("creating token...");
      Stripe.createToken(
        // Get the credit card details from the form
        // and input them here.
      }, stripeResponseHandler);

      // Prevent the form from submitting the normal way.
      return false;
    });
```

Just to reiterate, this all works fine when I test it manually. But my automated tests fail:

```
 Failure/Error: expect{submit_form}.to change{User.count}.by(1)
   expected result to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
```

When I try to use the gem `puffing-billy`, it seems to be caching `stripe.js` itself (which is loaded from Stripe's own servers at `js.stripe.com`, not served from my own app, as Stripe don't support this.), but the call initiated by `Stripe.createToken` isn't being cached. In fact, when I log into my Stripe server logs, it doesn't seem that the call is even been made (or at least Stripe isn't receiving it.)

Note those `console.log` statements in my JS above. When I run my test suite, the line "creating token..." gets printed, but "response handler called." doesn't. Looks like the response handler is never being called.

I've left out some details because this question is already very long, but can add more on request. What am I doing wrong here? How can I test my sign up page?

**UPDATE** See [my comment on this Github issue] on stripe-ruby-mock for more info on what I've tried and failed.

Comment: What does your feature spec look like?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the JS console?

Comment: Also, I didn't find any info on `Stripe.createToken`, shouldn't it be `Stripe.card.createToken`?

Comment: `Stripe.createToken` definitely exists, like I said this all works when I test it manually, I'm just struggling to write an automated test for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly...

Capybara won't know about your ajax requests. You should be able to stub out AJAX requests with Sinatra. Have it return a fixtures much the same as VCR.

Here's an article on it.

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/using-capybara-to-test-javascript-that-makes-http

You need to boot the Sinatra app in Capybara and then match the URLs in your ajax calls.

Something like:

```
class FakeContinousIntegration < Sinatra::Base
  def self.boot
    instance = new
    Capybara::Server.new(instance).tap { |server| server.boot }
  end

  get '/some/ajax'
    # send ajax back to capybara
  end
end
```

When you boot the server, it will return the address and port which you can write to a config that your js can use.

```
@server = App.boot
```

Then I use the address and port to config the JS app

```
def write_js_config
  config['api'] = "http://#{@server.host}:#{@server.port}"
  config.to_json
end
```

In `spec_helper.rb` send in the config to the js so your script points to your sinatra app. Mine compiles with gulp. So I just build the config into to is before the tests run:

```
system('gulp build --env capybara')
```

Comment: I have already tried exactly this, see my Github comment in the link I just added to my question. My problem is that, no matter how I set things up, stripe.js just doesn't seem to be calling my "Fake" app. I've changed `Stripe.endpoint` in the JS to point to my Sinatra app and changed `Stripe.api_base` in the Ruby and my app just never gets called. (And my tests aren't calling the real Stripe server either - nothing in my logs.) How can I find out where the call is going wrong?

Comment: (To clarify: I've added some logging functionally to my Sinatra app, and I can see that its actions (`get/post /v1/tokens` etc ) don't get called when I run my tests.

Comment: Let me add a bit more. I can do this with an angular js app so it should be working... wierd

Comment: If you console.log the api URL in your app does it match the port and address returned from booting your sinatra app?

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer, but shouldn't `@server = App.boot` be `@server = FakeContinousIntegration.boot`?

Comment: And where does `write_js_config` get called?

Comment: I eventually got it working with a version of this answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hello @GeorgeMillo , I'm having the exact same problem as you did in this question. However the answer is not clear for me yet. Where do you write the FakeContinuousIntegration class? How you boot the sinatra app when running the test? How to tell strip.js to connect to the sinatra app instead of the real stripe?

Will really appreciate your help

Comment: Setting `Stripe.endpoint` in `Stripe.js` is not officially supported.  This approach was viable until recently, but `Stripe.js` changed some things, and setting `Stripe.endpoint` is no longer a reliable way to point `Stripe.js` to your fake server.  Therefore, if you want to point to your own fake API server, you will need to use your own stub of `Stripe.js` itself rather than the real `Stripe.js`.

Answer (score 1):

I've had tests which worked on manual fail in Capybara/poltergeist due to timeout. In my case, the solution was to wait for all AJAX requests to finish. [Reference](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara)

Not sure whether Stripe.js uses JQuery internally, try checking for a condition set by `stripeResponseHandler`.

Comment: I've already tried the `wait_for_ajax` trick, but I didn't think to use a condition in stripeResponseHandler instead of of `jQuery.active`... which come to think of it is definitely the right idea because I'm pretty sure Stripe doesn't use jQuery! Let me try that and see if it works.....

Comment: Doesn't work. Added `window.stripeFlag = true` right before my call to `createToken`. Added `window.stripeFlag = false` as the first line of the `stripeResponseHandler` callback. Changed the method in `wait_for_ajax`  to `page.evaluate_script("window.stripeFlag").strip == "false"` (and added wait_for_ajax to my specs... well, actually, it was already there). And it still doesn't work. `stripeResponseHandler` never gets called; it seems that stripe.js just isn't hitting the external API, either Stripe's real one or my own stubbed one.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `wait_for_ajax` trick mentioned, it looks like you are calling `expect` before your database was updated. One way to check that would be to add a breakpoint in your code(`binding.pry`), and check if it is a race condition issue or not.

Also, as per [Capybara's documentation](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#asynchronous-javascript-ajax-and-friends), introducing an expectation of a UI change makes it 'smartly' wait for ajax calls to finish:

```
expect(page).not_to have_content('Enter credit card details')
```